# Align Drop Down Menu Title to prevent overlapping of other buttons

Tags: swift, user-interface, drop-down-menu, menu, title

I have the below image where the title of the drop down menu title is overlapped with other buttons. **How to solve this issue?**

[image]

Code:

```
func createDropDownMenu() {

    // create the drop down menu
    let title = prepareNavigationBarMenuTitleView()
    prepareNavigationBarMenu(title)
    updateMenuContentOffsets()

}

func prepareNavigationBarMenuTitleView() -> String {

    // Both title label and image view are fixed horizontally inside title
    // view, UIKit is responsible to center title view in the navigation bar.
    // We want to ensure the space between title and image remains constant,
    // even when title view is moved to remain centered (but never resized).
    titleView = DropDownTitleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
    titleView.addTarget(self,
                        action: #selector(DocumentViewController.willToggleNavigationBarMenu(_:)),
                        for: .touchUpInside)
    titleView.addTarget(self,
                        action: #selector(DocumentViewController.didToggleNavigationBarMenu(_:)),
                        for: .valueChanged)


    titleView.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byClipping
    titleView.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    titleView.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    titleView.title = currentNode.title
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    return titleView.title!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the frame of the TitleLable and set the numberOfLines = 0 to solve my problem.

Code:

```
titleView.titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 80)
titleView.numberOfLines = 0

titleView.titleLabel.text = currentNode.title
```